# Swift 2.0 and Foundation enums/structs?

Tags: swift, enums, foundation, swift2, xcode7

After opening my project up in Xcode 7, one of the more surprising changes I had to make was changing enum/struct code (I originally only mentioned enums in this post but apparently `NSCalendarUnit` is an enum in Obj-C and a struct in Swift -- what's up with that?) like `NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth` to `NSCalendarUnit.NSMonthCalendarUnit`. I'm perfectly able to make such changes, obviously. Yet I want to know *why?*

Answer (score 1):

That's the new [OptionSetType](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html) that replaces the binary operations you used to have to do when Objective-C `NS_OPTION` enums were imported into Swift.